# Use List<string> created in one method and use in another

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I am working on a quiz app that takes a group of questions from my DB and displays each question once after a button click, preferably without duplicating the same question. I have a method called on initialization which gets an array of two arrays from my db, then splits it into two the separate arrays. One of those arrays I then want to use in another method. This is the first method (at the moment I am creating an array string from the list and storing that as a global variable for future use - I am also using a random value from that list to display in a textview):

```
private class showNextRandomQuestion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

                    //get the data from the database
                    List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion2();

                    //Get the question/text/answer Strings
                    List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question Strings
                    List<String> answerSetIds = listList.get(1);                            

                    //Generate random index
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int rand = Math.abs((r.nextInt() % questionStrings.size()));

                    //get answer description for randomly selected question
                    String questionString = questionStrings.get(rand);  
                    String answerSetId = answerSetIds.get(rand);

                    questionstringarray = questionStrings.toString();


                    //remove and square brackets from array of strings
                    String regex = "\\[|\\]";
                    answerId = answerSetId.replaceAll(regex, "");
                    mQuestionString = questionString.replaceAll(regex, "");
                    return mQuestionString; 
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //take returned question from above and display it
                 questionView.setText(mQuestionString); 
            }
        }
```

I am for some reason really struggling to figure out how I can use the list as it is rather than converting it into a string array ('questionstringarray'). You'll see from my next method, which is triggered by button click, that I had tried to take that string array and turn it back into a list, so I could use it again.

```
private class showNextRandomQuestion2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();   

                    //remove and square brackets from array of strings
                    String regex = "\\[|\\]";

                    questionstringarray = questionstringarray.replaceAll(regex, "");

                    StringTokenizer questionDescr = new StringTokenizer(questionstringarray, ",");

                    first = questionDescr.nextToken();
                    first = first.trim();
                    second = questionDescr.nextToken();
                    second = second.trim();
                    third = questionDescr.nextToken();
                    third = third.trim();
                    fourth = questionDescr.nextToken();
                    fourth = fourth.trim();
                    fifth = questionDescr.nextToken();
                    fifth = fifth.trim();

                    array1.add(first);
                    array1.add(second);
                    array1.add(third);
                    array1.add(fourth);
                    array1.add(fifth);

                    Collections.shuffle(array1);

                    //remove and square brackets from array of strings
                    String regex1 = "\\[|\\]";
                    //remove values from string when shuffling through so not repeated
                    String bQuestionText = array1.remove(0);

                    bQuestionString = bQuestionText.replaceAll(regex1, "");
                    return bQuestionString; 

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //take returned question from above and display it
                 questionView.setText(bQuestionString);  

            }
        }
```

I don't obviously want to convert from a list in one method only to convert it back to a list in the next. Ultimately I want the first method to get the data from my db which I am happy with - display one of the strings within that method, then store that same list for use in another method where I will display the next string in the list (hopefully then remove it from the list) and on button click display then next string, and next.... - hence the 'Collections.shuffle'.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

And here is my new class which retrieves and stores the list  for further use:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Application;

public class QuizQuestionBank extends Application {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private List<String> questionStrings;


public List<String> getQuestionStrings(List<String> questionStrings2) {

SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(QuizQuestionBank.this);

//get the data from the database
List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion2();

//              questionStrings.clear();

//Get the question/text/answer Strings
List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question Strings
//              List<String> answerSetIds = listList.get(1); 

return questionStrings;
}

public List<String> setQuestionStrings(List<String> questionStrings) {
return this.questionStrings = questionStrings;
}

}
```

Comment: First of all, create a class `Question.java` then try to handle shuffle and other operations `List<Question> questions` object.. Lastly, 
arrange ui.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you have three concerns here;
 1. Return required data from the database, ensure it is in an appropriate format for all client methods.
 2. Store the returned data
 3. Select (random) question from the returned data.

I would return the data from the database in one method, the return from which I would then store in an instance variable of a class, perhaps called `QuizQuestionBank` or some such.  This would have a method from which a question will be returned.

This way the method return the question can choose a random question from the list or simple the top one, or remove the used questions from listed.  Depending on your requirement and it is transparent to the client class, all the client class knows if it calls method on `QuizQuestionBank` and a question is returned, it doenst worry about how that may be stored or selected.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use a class for your Question object.
and after getting list of questions from db in a list variable, store that variable data with Application Class using setter methods and whenever required get it by calling getter method(of Application class) inside activity.
and use any shuffling method before starting quiz session(new attempt of quiz).

**Edited:**
Use it like below:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Application;

public class QuizQuestionBank extends Application {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private List<String> questionStrings;


public List<String> getQuestionStrings() {
    return questionStrings;
}

public List<String> setQuestionStrings(List<String> questionStrings) {
    return this.questionStrings = questionStrings;
}

}
```

Now use the code to get data from Database only once, before starting quiz,
and put that data into QuizQuestionBank class's questionStrings variable using setter method.
Set it from activity like below:

```
((QuizQuestionBank) getApplication()).setQuestionStrings(List<String> questionStrings);
```

And get it within an activity like below:

```
List<String> questionStrings = ((QuizQuestionBank) getApplication()).getQuestionStrings();
```

or get it within a fragment:

```
List<String> questionStrings = ((QuizQuestionBank) getActivity().getApplication()).getQuestionStrings();
```

of if any other class:

```
List<String> questionStrings = ((QuizQuestionBank) context.getApplicationContext()).getQuestionStrings();
```

where context(Context type) will be initialized with passed context argument.

Comment: Thanks both - much appreciated. I am struggling somewhat to implement this still. I have created a new class 'QuizQuestionBank.java' as suggested - and have added to the question above. It does not think the QuestionStrings() method in MainActivity matches the arguments in this class.

Comment: Also try to use Question.java to create a question object (POJO). And replace List<String> questionStrings with List<Question> questions, it will make your life easy :)